# Possible to suggest tag(s) after scanning through the question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

Is it possible to add this feature - after user enter his/her question into the question text area, the website will auto insert some suggested tags for the question and insert them automatically in the Tags field?

Thanks.

Comment: I like this idea! Would be cool if based on some keywords in the post you could suggest tags.

Comment: But - these keywords are already (almost) tags, aren't they?

Answer (score 2):

At this point [this feature isn't on the cards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/auto-tagging).

The human element in choosing the best tags is very important and cannot be ignored. Having questions posted with wrong tags automatically selected is too much of a risk.